# Proving 1:1 and onto of 2 variable function

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $\ f: \mathbb Q^2\to\mathbb Q^2$ be defined by $\ f(x,y) = (x-3y , x + 3y- 1)$
Prove the function is 1:1, onto, find the inverse and $\ f \circ f $.

I was able to prove 1:1 by showing $\ f(x_1,y_1)=f(x_2,y_2) \implies (x_1,y_1)=(x_2,y_2) $, which was relatively simple, but i'm having a hard time using the definition of the onto function with this 2 variable function.

Any push in the right direction would be helpful.

Comment: **Hint:**

Given $(r,s)\in\mathbb{Q}^2$ you must show that there exist $(x,y)\in\mathbb{Q}^2$ such that
\begin{align*}
x-3y&=r\\
x+3y-1&=s
\end{align*}

Comment: So isolating x and y and showing that they belong to Q is proof enough?

Comment: Yes, it is enough.

Comment: Start by finding the inverse (which is not difficult).